# How can I destroy a game object and instantiate a new prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, prefab

I am developing a game with Unity 2d, and I am trying to make the player disappear when it reaches the TorchSwordBool. I was successful doing so, but when I tried to instantiate a prefab for the player with torch and sword equipped, it starts an animation loop of the player picking the sword and torch infinitely.

This is the code that I am using (The instance for the game object is in the end):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementNoSword : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float move;

    [SerializeField] private bool TorchSwordBool = false;
    [SerializeField] private Transform TorchSword;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject CharacterSword;

    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 3f;

    [SerializeField]private bool jumping; 
    [SerializeField] private float jumpSpeed = 4.8f;

    [SerializeField] private float ghostJump;

    [SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform feetPosition;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 sizeCapsule;
    [SerializeField] private float angleCapsule = -90;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sprite;
    Animator animationPlayer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animationPlayer = GetComponent<Animator>();

        sizeCapsule = new Vector2 (0.302f, 0.01f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(TorchSwordBool == false)
        {
            //Detect Ground
            isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCapsule(feetPosition.position, sizeCapsule, CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal, angleCapsule, whatIsGround);

            //Player's movement input
            move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            if (move !=0) {
                moveSpeed += 15f * Time.deltaTime;

                if (moveSpeed >= 3.0f)
                {
                    moveSpeed = 3.0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                moveSpeed = 0;
            }

            //Player's jumping input
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && ghostJump > 0)
            {
                jumping = true;
            }

            //Flip in the horizontal direction
            if(move < 0)
            {
                sprite.flipX = true;
            }
            else if(move > 0)
            {
                sprite.flipX = false;
            }


            if (isGrounded)
            {
                ghostJump = 0.05f;

                animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingV", false);
                animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingV", false);
                animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingH", false);
                //animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingH", false);

                if (rb.velocity.x != 0 && move != 0)
                {
                    animationPlayer.SetBool("Walking", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    animationPlayer.SetBool("Walking", false);  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ghostJump -= Time.deltaTime;

                if(ghostJump <= 0)
                {
                    ghostJump = 0;
                }   

                if (rb.velocity.x == 0)
                {
                    animationPlayer.SetBool("Walking", false);

                    if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
                    {
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingV", true);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingV", false);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingH", false);
                        //animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingH", false);
                    }
                    if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
                    {
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingV", false);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingV", true);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingH", false);
                        //animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingH", false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
                    {
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingV", false);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingV", false);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingH", true);
                        //animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingH", false);
                    }
                    if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
                    {
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingV", false);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingV", true);
                        animationPlayer.SetBool("JumpingH", false);
                        //animationPlayer.SetBool("FallingH", true);
                    }
                }   
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            animationPlayer.SetBool("Walking", false);
            animationPlayer.SetBool("PickST", true);
        }


    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
        Gizmos.DrawCube(feetPosition.position, sizeCapsule);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(TorchSwordBool == false)
        {
            //Player's movement
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

            //Player's jump
            if(jumping)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;
                //rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0f, jumpSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                jumping = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D Coll)
    {
        if(Coll.gameObject.tag == "TorchSword" && isGrounded)
        {
            TorchSwordBool = true;
            sprite.flipX = false;
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePosition;
            transform.position = TorchSword.position;
        }
    }

    void DestroyTorchNSword()
    {
        Destroy(TorchSword.gameObject);
    }

    void DestroyPlayer()
    {
        Instantiate(CharacterSword, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no call to `DestroyPlayer()`.  The script is stuck in the outer else condition in `Update`.

Comment: This is not the way to approach this situation- a better way to do this is to have the sword and torch in the player, but disabled. When you want the player to have the torch and sword, simply enable those objects, and whatever else you need.

Answer (score 0):

why in your func DestroyPlayer you Instantiate a CharacterSword? Is it tag with “ TorchSword”

Comment: This is not an answer. Post a comment instead of an answer if you want to say something/ask questions that don't help in answering the question by op.